# Adding xml:space to root element

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml, xml-namespaces, xattribute

I have a little problem that I thought was a no-brainer ... but alas ...

I have some xml and all I want to do is to add the `xml:space="preserve"` to the root element using c#.

I tried this:

```
var rootElem = xDoc.Root; // XDocument
rootElem.SetAttributeValue("{xml}space", "preserve");
```

The result of this is:

```
<ProjectDetails xmlns="http://site/ppm" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" p3:space="preserve" xmlns:p3="xml">
```

I *think* this is equivalent to

```
<ProjectDetails xmlns="http://site/ppm" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xml:space="preserve">
```

But since `xml:space` is a special attribute, I am a bit in doubt.

So:

Are they identical?

Is there a way I can add this to the document in a "clean" way?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You just need the right `XName` value - I'd use this:

```
doc.Root.SetAttributeValue(XNamespace.Xml + "space", "preserve");
```

The `XName +(XNamespace, string)` operator is generally the simplest way to work with namespaces in LINQ to XML, in my experience.